# Como somar tempos em Java?

Tags: java, time

Estou trabalhando em um relatório que faz um somatório dos dados e parte dos dados são tempos, exemplo:

```
 -----------------------
| Atividade |   Tempo   |
 -----------------------
|    1      |  11:00:00 |
 -----------------------
|    2      |  12:00:00 |
 -----------------------
|    3      |  13:00:00 |
 -----------------------
| Total     |  36:00:00 |
 -----------------------
```

Estou tentando somar os tempos dessa maneira:

```
final DateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
c.setTimeInMillis(0);
for (final String h : listaHoras) {
    c.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, (int) dt.parse(h).getTime());
}
```

A variável `listaHoras` é um [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) de `String`'s todas no formato respeitado pelo [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). O problema do código acima é que não consigo gerar o valor somado, usando o mesmo `SimpleDateFormat` ele me retorna o horário de um dia lá na frente de acordo com a data, mas dentro das 24 horas.

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Em total deveria parecer 2:00:00, que no caso é o intervalo entre 11:00 e 13:00? Pelo que entendi ela está somando 11 + 12 + 13 = 36, você precisa somente exibir o intervalo entre o primeiro horário e o último certo?

Comment: @EduardoBentoRochaJunior Na verdade não preciso da diferença não, preciso da soma mesmo.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

O mais fácil e conveniente é usar o [`Duration`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_duration.html) do JodaTime, mas talvez não faça muito sentido adicionar essa dependência se você precisar calcular datas apenas nesta parte.

Infelizmente, a forma mais fácil de se fazer isso usando apenas as bibliotecas nativas é parecido com o que já fez, mas ao invés de utilizar um `Calendar`, calcular manualmente o total.

Por exemplo:

```
// estes numeros nem sempre sao verdade, mas deve ser suficiente para seu caso
long SECOND = 1000;
long MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
long HOUR = 60 * MINUTE;
long DAY = 24 * HOUR;

// somatoria dos getTime, semelhante ao codigo que ja tens
long elapsedTimeInMilliseconds = ...

double elapsedDays = Math.floor(elapsedTimeInMilliseconds / DAY);
long remaining = elapsedTimeInMilliseconds % DAY; // resto da divisao acima
double elapsedHours = Math.floor(remaining / HOUR);
remaining = remaining % HOUR;
// e por ai vai, ate chegar nos segundos (se for o caso)
```

EDIT: 
Esta resposta era perfeitamente válida em 2014. Hoje, uma [API muito semelhante à do JodaTime está disponível no Java SE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html), logo, não faz sentido fazer este cálculo manualmente se a plataforma onde o código for rodar suportar Java 8.

Comment: Realmente acho o jodatime melhor que a api do SE, tanto que iremos ver o modo jodatime de trabalhar com datas e tempos na próxima versão do java

Comment: Tenho a [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/) aqui em uma versão bem defasada da atual que é a *2.3* e eu tenho a *1.6.2*. Nunca a utilizei, mas lendo o link que você me mandou da classe Duration parece simples. Ela resolvendo meu problema ou fazendo na unha eu te retorno como resposta aceita, de qualquer maneira já tem um +1 pelo algoritmo via SE.

Comment: Olha a resposta que aceitei no SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230487/how-to-sum-times-in-java. Era o que você estava imaginando?

Comment: Sim, exatamente isso. Onde eu coloquei elapsedTimeInMilliseconds fica "long tm = sum.getTime().getTime();" . O resto do calculo é semelhante :-)

Comment: Então aceitarei sua resposta, mas colocarei a que eu cheguei através dele para possíveis comentários e melhorias.

Comment: Fiz uma atualização na minha resposta. Poderia ler e fazer suas considerações?

Answer (score 8):

Cheguei a esse código após [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230487/how-to-sum-times-in-java) no SO e postarei para possíveis críticas.

```
public static void somaTempos(final String[] listaTempos) throws ParseException {
    long tm = 0;
    final DateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
    for (String tmp : listaTempos) {
        c.setTime(dt.parse(tmp));
        tm += c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + 60 * c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 3600 * c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    }

    final long l = tm % 3600;
    System.out.println(SIGRUtil.format(tm / 3600) + ':' + SIGRUtil.format(l / 60) + ':' + SIGRUtil.format(l % 60));
}

private static String format(long s) {
    if (s < 10) {
        return "0" + s;
    }
    return String.valueOf(s);
}
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Ainda trabalhando na solução desenvolvi o seguinte código.

```
public static String somaTempos(final List<String> listaTempos) {
    long milissegundos = 0;
    final DateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    dt.setLenient(false);
    try {
        // Deslocamento de fuso-horário.
        final long timezoneOffset = dt.parse("00:00:00").getTime();
        for (final String tempo : listaTempos) {
            milissegundos += (dt.parse(tempo).getTime() - timezoneOffset);
        }
    } catch (final ParseException e) {
        throw new BusinessException(
                "Lista de tempos deve ser passada com os tempos respeitando o padrão HH:mm:ss.", e);
    }

    ((SimpleDateFormat) dt).applyPattern(":mm:ss");
    return new StringBuilder(8).append(milissegundos / DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_HOUR).append(
            dt.format(new Date(milissegundos))).toString();
}
```

Na verdade, a API me dá de graça os minutos e segundos após fazer o cálculo da soma dos tempos sem esquecer de considerar o deslocamento de fuso-horário. O meu verdadeiro problema era calcular o número de horas em uma determinada data, que na verdade era o ponto mais fácil do problema e que foi a primeira parte que consegui resolver.

Considerações de melhorias no código?

Answer (score 5):

Como é algo especifico de horas, pode usar [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) que fornece o método [`plusHours`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#plusHours-long-) para realizar soma de horas. Existem outros métodos para tratar soma de minutos, segundos, etc (`TODO:` ver documentação da classe).

```
LocalTime primeiro = LocalTime.of(12, 0); // 12:00
LocalTime segundo  = LocalTime.of(5, 45); //  5:45

LocalTime total = primeiro.plusHours(segundo.getHour())
                          .plusMinutes(segundo.getMinute());

System.out.println(total); // 17:45
```

#### Funcionando no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/oLw32S)

Se estiver trabalhando com strings, há o método [`parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) para obter um objeto `LocalTime` a partir de uma sequência de caracteres:

```
LocalTime primeiro = LocalTime.parse("12:00");
LocalTime segundo  = LocalTime.parse("05:45");

LocalTime total = primeiro.plusHours(segundo.getHour())
                          .plusMinutes(segundo.getMinute());

System.out.println(total); // 17:45
```

#### Funcionando no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/TmCKjY)

Comment: Isso só funciona se o total for menor ou igual a `23:59:59.999999999`: https://ideone.com/IsbHnA - O problema é que `LocalTime` não foi feito para trabalhar com durações (este uso seria um *hack* limitado), o ideal neste caso seria usar `java.time.Duration` - já que vai usar o `java.time`, por que não usar logo as classes corretas para isso? :-) Entendo que o fato de poder fazer *parsing* diretamente pode parecer uma vantagem, mas o fato de não funcionar com totais maiores que 24 horas já me faz não escolher esta solução... :-)

Comment: Como ele disse que quer "somar os tempos" e o total dá 36 horas, então se trata de durações :-)

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente, temos que entender a diferença entre horários e durações:

- um **horário** representa **um momento específico** do dia. Ex: a reunião será às duas horas da tarde (diz exatamente em qual momento do dia será a reunião)
- uma **duração** representa **uma quantidade de tempo**. Ex: a reunião durou duas horas (eu não disse que horas ela começou ou terminou, só disse quanto tempo ela durou)

O que pode confundir é que tanto horários quanto durações usam as mesmas palavras (horas, minutos e segundos), e muitas vezes são escritos do mesmo jeito ("11:00" pode ser tanto 11 da manhã quanto uma duração de 11 horas). Mas cada um representa um conceito diferente.

---

O que acontece é que [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) e [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) servem para trabalhar com datas e horários, **mas não com durações**.

Em alguns casos, pode até "funcionar", mas será por coincidência. Por exemplo, ao fazer *parsing* de `11:00:00` como se fosse um horário:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse("11:00:00");
System.out.println(date);
```

Este código imprime:

> Thu Jan 01 11:00:00 BRT 1970

<sup>Lembrando que a saída pode variar, já que ao imprimir um `Date`, é [usado o fuso horário correspondente ao timezone *default* da JVM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/372560/112052) (no caso, o "BRT" indica o Horário de Brasília, já que na minha JVM o timezone *default* é `America/Sao_Paulo`).</sup>

Repare que a data resultante é "1 de janeiro de 1970, às 11 da manhã". **Isso é uma data e hora, não uma duração**. Você até poderia usar o valor de `date.getTime()` e corrigir de acordo com o *offset* do timezone (como você fez [na sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8337/112052)), mas a verdade é que esta solução não é a ideal, já que você está tratando datas e horas como se fossem durações. Você está basicamente usando uma chave de fenda para martelar um prego (pode até "funcionar", mas não é a maneira ideal).

[image]

Infelizmente a API legada (`Date`, `Calendar` e `SimpleDateFormat`) não possui nenhum mecanismo para trabalhar com durações (inclusive, [foi um dos muitos motivos que levaram à criação da API do Java 8](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310#2)). A solução, neste caso, é fazer como sugeriu a [resposta do @jpkrohling](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8284/112052): manipular as strings e fazer as contas manualmente.

```
List<String> listaTempos = Arrays.asList("11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00");
long totalSegundos = 0;
for (String tempo : listaTempos) {
    String[] partes = tempo.split(":");
    long horas = Long.parseLong(partes[0]);
    long minutos = Long.parseLong(partes[1]);
    long segundos = Long.parseLong(partes[2]);
    totalSegundos += segundos + (minutos * 60) + (horas * 3600);
}
long totalHoras = totalSegundos / 3600;
totalSegundos %= 3600;
long totalMinutos = totalSegundos / 60;
totalSegundos %= 60;
String totalFormatado = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", totalHoras, totalMinutos, totalSegundos);
System.out.println(totalFormatado); // 36:00:00
```

---

## Java >= 8

A partir do Java 8 você pode usar a API [`java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052). Além de ser muito superior a `Date` e `Calendar`, ela também possui classes específicas para lidar com durações. No caso, podemos usar um [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html):

```
List<String> listaTempos = Arrays.asList("11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00");
Duration total = Duration.ZERO;
for (String tempo : listaTempos) {
    String[] partes = tempo.split(":");
    total = total
        // somar horas
        .plusHours(Long.parseLong(partes[0]))
        // somar minutos
        .plusMinutes(Long.parseLong(partes[1]))
        // somar segundos
        .plusSeconds(Long.parseLong(partes[2]));
}
```

Com isso, a variável `total` representará um `Duration` contendo a duração total. Infelizmente a API ainda não provê um mecanismo para formatar adequadamente uma duração, então o jeito é fazer as contas manualmente, de maneira similar à solução anterior:

```
// obter o total de segundos do Duration
long totalSegundos = total.getSeconds();
// daqui pra baixo é igual ao código anterior
long totalHoras = totalSegundos / 3600;
totalSegundos %= 3600;
long totalMinutos = totalSegundos / 60;
totalSegundos %= 60;
String totalFormatado = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", totalHoras, totalMinutos, totalSegundos);
System.out.println(totalFormatado); // 36:00:00
```

Só um detalhe: a classe `Duration` possui o método [`toMinutes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMinutes--), que *aparentemente* poderia ser usado. Mas neste caso ele retornará `2160`, pois é o **total** de minutos correspondente a duração total (que corresponde a 36 horas). Para obter a duração "quebrada" em horas, minutos e segundos, a única solução - pelo menos no Java 8 - é fazer as contas manualmente.

#### Java >= 9

A partir do Java 9 foram criados métodos como [`toMinutesPart()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMinutesPart--), que já trazem esses valores devidamente "quebrados". Ou seja, para Java >= 9, a parte final (depois do `for`) ficaria:

```
for (String tempo: listaTempos) {
    ... // igual ao exemplo anterior
}
String totalFormatado = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", (total.toDaysPart() * 24) + total.toHoursPart(),
                                      total.toMinutesPart(), total.toSecondsPart());
System.out.println(totalFormatado); // 36:00:00
```

No caso, precisei pegar também o valor de [`toDaysPart()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toDaysPart--), já que uma duração de 36 horas é retornada como "1 dia e 12 horas" pelos respectivos métodos `toDaysPart()` e `toHoursPart()`. Um detalhe meio chato, mas ainda sim, bem melhor do que fazer as contas manualmente.

#### Java 6 e 7

Para o Java 6 e 7, a solução é fazer as contas manualmente, como já sugerido. Mas existe também uma alternativa: usar o [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), um *backport* do `java.time`, que possui basicamente as mesmas classes e funcionalidades do Java 8 (não 100%, claro, mas as principais classes e métodos estão disponíveis).

O código fica igual ao exemplo anterior do Java 8, a diferença é que em vez do pacote `java.time`, usa-se o pacote `org.threeten.bp`.

#### Java 5

Finalmente, para o Java 5 (além da primeira solução de fazer as contas manualmente), uma alternativa é usar o [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Esta biblioteca contém inclusive a classe [`org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html) para fazer o *parsing* e formatação de uma duração:

```
import org.joda.time.Duration;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder;

List<String> listaTempos = Arrays.asList("11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00");
PeriodFormatter fmt = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2)
    .appendHours().appendSeparator(":")
    .appendMinutes().appendSeparator(":")
    .appendSeconds().toFormatter();
Duration total = Duration.ZERO;
for (String tempo : listaTempos) {
    total = total.plus(fmt.parsePeriod(tempo).toStandardDuration());
}
String totalFormatado = fmt.print(total.toPeriod());
System.out.println(totalFormatado); // 36:00:00
```

Lembrando que o Joda-Time é um projeto "encerrado" e em seu próprio site [há um aviso](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/#Support) sobre isso, recomendando a migração para o `java.time`. De qualquer forma, para quem ainda está "preso" ao Java 5, é uma ótima alternativa à `Date` e `Calendar`.

Note também que a classe `Duration` está no pacote `org.joda.time` (não confundir com o `java.time.Duration` do Java >= 8). O Joda-Time não é 100% idêntico ao `java.time`, mas muitos dos seus conceitos e ideias foram aproveitados no Java 8 (inclusive algumas classes e métodos possuem os mesmos nomes). As principais semelhanças e diferenças entre as APIs são explicadas [aqui](http://blog.joda.org/2009/11/why-jsr-310-isn-joda-time_4941.html) e [aqui](http://blog.joda.org/2014/11/converting-from-joda-time-to-javatime.html).

---

### Não confunda datas/horas com durações

[Uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/172608/112052) está usando [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) para representar as durações. Mas esta classe representa um horário, não uma duração. Isso quer dizer que ela só "funciona" caso o total seja menos que 23 horas e 59 minutos. Ex:

```
LocalTime primeiro = LocalTime.parse("12:00");
LocalTime segundo = LocalTime.parse("17:00");
LocalTime total = primeiro.plusHours(segundo.getHour()).plusMinutes(segundo.getMinute());
System.out.println(total); // 05:00
```

Somando uma duração de 12 horas com outra de 17 horas, o resultado deveria ser um total de 29 horas. Mas como `LocalTime` representa um horário (e não uma duração), ela só suporta valores até `23:59:59.999999999`, e depois disso ela "volta" para meia-noite. Por isso o resultado é `05:00` (5 da manhã - novamente, um horário, não uma duração).

É a mesma história de `Date` e `SimpleDateFormat`: usar classes que representam datas e horas para trabalhar com durações nem sempre funcionará. Muitas vezes será apenas por coincidência, e mesmo assim para casos limitados (como foi o caso da já citada resposta que usou `LocalTime`). [Funcionar é diferente de estar certo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgk8Q.png).

Se você já tem disponível as classes do `java.time`, use os tipos corretos para cada caso. Se precisa lidar com horários, use `LocalTime`. Se precisa lidar com durações, use `Duration` (ou [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html)).

Comment: Se puderem dizer o problema da resposta para merecer um negativo, agradeço. Ficarei feliz em corrigir o problema..