# Alterar somente horas, minutos, segundos de um objeto Date

Tags: java, datetime, data

Preciso alterar somente as horas de um objeto do tipo `Date`, preservando o dia o mês e o ano.

Tentei com o `setMinutes()`, `setSeconds()`, `setHours()`, mas aparece "is deprecated".

> 31/03/2019 13:23:14.958 <<<<<< Ela vem assim do Banco
>
> 31/03/2019 13:23:14.958  <<<<<< Fica assim no objeto Java
>
> 31/03/2019 23:59:59.999 <<<< Preciso que ela fique assim pra passar pra uma função.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro temos que entender o que realmente a classe [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) significa. Apesar do nome, ela não representa uma data. Pelo menos não no sentido de representar um único valor de dia, mês, ano, hora, minuto e segundo.

Na verdade um `Date` representa um [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052). O único valor que ela possui é um `long`: um número que representa a quantidade de milissegundos desde o [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (sendo que o Unix Epoch é 1 de janeiro de 1970, à meia-noite em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)). O valor do timestamp pode ser obtido pelo método [`getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--).

O que pode confundir ao usar `Date` é que ao imprimi-la, o timezone *default* da JVM é usado para traduzir o timestamp para uma data e hora. 
Um teste clássico é imprimir o `Date` várias vezes, mudando o timezone *default*:

```
Date d = new Date();
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
System.out.println(d.getTime() + "=" + d);
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
System.out.println(d.getTime() + "=" + d);
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"));
System.out.println(d.getTime() + "=" + d);
```

A saída é:

> 1554052464000=Sun Mar 31 14:14:24 BRT 2019
>   1554052464000=Sun Mar 31 10:14:24 PDT 2019
>   1554052464000=Mon Apr 01 02:14:24 JST 2019

Repare que o valor do timestamp (retornado por `getTime()`) não muda, ou seja, o `Date` é sempre o mesmo. Mas ao imprimi-lo, ele usa o timezone *default* para obter os valores de data e hora. Veja que em São Paulo o dia é 31/03/2019 e o horário é 14:14:24. Mas em Los Angeles o horário é 10:14, e no Japão já é dia 01/04 às 02:14 da manhã.

Essa é a ideia do timestamp: seu valor é o mesmo no mundo todo (não importa onde está o computador nem qual timezone está configurado, todos iriam obter 1554052464000 como o timestamp atual se rodassem este código no mesmo instante que eu). O que muda são os valores de data e hora correspondentes, pois estes variam de um fuso horário para outro.

Portanto, o que um `java.util.Date` representa é o valor do timestamp. Qualquer valor derivado dele (dia, mês, ano, hora, minuto, segundo) depende do timezone *default* da JVM. Mas esses valores **não** fazem parte do `Date`. Quando você usa os *getters* e *setters*, ele verifica o timezone *default* da JVM e o timestamp, e verifica qual o respectivo valor do campo nestas condições.

---

Dito isso, pela saída que você informou, parece que você está usando na verdade um [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html). E como esta é uma subclasse de `java.util.Date`, ela possui as mesmas características: tudo que ela possui é o valor do timestamp, e se você imprimi-la, os valores de data e hora também mudam conforme o timezone *default* da JVM.

De qualquer forma, para manipular os campos, você pode usar um [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
Date d = ...
Timestamp t = ...

// criar o Calendar
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

// setar o timestamp
cal.setTimeInMillis(t.getTime());
// se for usar o timestamp de Date, faça
// cal.setTimeInMillis(d.getTime()); ou simplesmente cal.setTime(d);

// mudar o horário para 23:59:59.999
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);

// criar novas instâncias com o horário atualizado
t = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
d = cal.getTime();
```

Sempre lembrando que `Calendar` também trabalhará com o timezone *default* da JVM. Se você quiser a data e hora em um timezone diferente, deve passá-lo no método `getInstance()`:

```
// usar timezone do Japão em vez do default da JVM
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"));
```

O timezone usado irá gerar um valor diferente de timestamp, já que 23:59 ocorre em um instante diferente em cada parte do mundo. Na maior parte das vezes as pessoas simplesmente usam o *default* sem pensar porque todos os servidores estão configurados com o mesmo timezone e tudo "funciona". Mas é importante ter em mente que o timezone escolhido pode influenciar os valores finais.

---

Outro detalhe é que datas não têm formato (<sup><sub>Conforme já dito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/364683/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/368075/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367704/112052).</sub></sup>)

A saída que você vê (`31/03/2019 13:23:14.958`) é apenas uma forma que as classes escolheram para representar seus valores. No caso do `java.sql.Timestamp`, por padrão ele converte o timestamp para o timezone *default* da JVM, obtém os respectivos valores de data e hora e mostra nesse formato. Mas isso não quer dizer que a data **está** nesse formato.

---

### Java >= 8

A partir do Java 8 existe a [API `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052), muito melhor do que as classes legadas (`Date`, `Calendar`, etc).

Nesta API, você pode escolher o tipo mais adequado para trabalhar com suas datas. No caso, você pode por exemplo mapear o `java.sql.Timestamp` para um [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html):

```
Timestamp t = ...
LocalDateTime ldt = t
    // converte para LocalDateTime (usa o timezone default da JVM)
    .toLocalDateTime()
    // seta o horário para 23:59:59.999999999
    .with(LocalTime.MAX);
// converte de volta para Timestamp
t = Timestamp.valueOf(ldt);
```

Usei [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) para setar o horário, e a constante [`MAX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MAX) que corresponde a 23:59:59.999999999.

As conversões de/para `LocalDateTime` usam o timezone *default* da JVM para saber os valores de data e hora correspondentes ao timestamp. Mas se quiser usar um timezone específico, pode converter as classes para [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) (a classe que representa o conceito de timestamp), e em seguida usar um [`java.time.ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) (a classe que representa um timezone).

```
Date d = ...
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"); // timezone que quero usar na conversão
ZonedDateTime zdt = d.toInstant() // obtém o Instant (representa o timestamp)
    // converte para um timezone
    .atZone(zone)
    // obtém a data e o início do dia seguinte
    .toLocalDate().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(zone)
    // subtrai 1 nanossegundo (para obter o último instante do dia anterior)
    .minusNanos(1);
// converte de volta para Date
d = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
// este código também funciona para java.sql.Timestamp
// pois esta classe também possui os métodos toInstant() e from(Instant)
```

O resultado é um [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). A diferença é que esta classe considera o timezone, e `LocalDateTime` não.

Provavelmente você está se perguntando para que toda essa complicação de obter o início do dia seguinte e subtrair 1 nanossegundo. Isso acontece porque timezones possuem horário de verão e se eu simplesmente setar o horário para 23:59:59.999, nem sempre o resultado será o último instante daquele dia. No exemplo anterior a esse eu pude fazer isso porque `LocalDateTime` não tem informações sobre o timezone e por isso não sofre interferência do horário de verão.

Por exemplo, quando acaba o horário de verão no Brasil, à meia-noite o relógio é atrasado 1 hora, de volta para 23:00. Ou seja, os minutos entre 23:00 e 23:59 ocorrem duas vezes, uma no horário de verão e outra no horário normal. Se eu setar o horário para 23:59 manualmente, qual dessas ocorrências será setada, a do horário de verão ou do horário normal? Para evitar esses problemas, o método acima é mais garantido, pois eu pego o último instante do dia, no timezone em questão, independente de ter horário de verão ou não.

---

Caso o banco de dados que você está usando tenha um driver compatível com o **JDBC 4.2**, é possível trabalhar diretamente com as classes do `java.time`, usando os métodos `setObject` da classe [`java.sql.PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) e `getObject` da classe [`java.sql.ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html). Um exemplo com `LocalDateTime` seria:

```
LocalDateTime dt = ...
PreparedStatement ps = ...
// seta o java.time.LocalDateTime
ps.setObject(1, dt);

// obter o LocalDateTime do banco
ResultSet rs = ...
LocalDateTime dt = rs.getObject(1, LocalDateTime.class);
...
```

Só lembrando que nem todos os bancos de dados suportam todos os tipos do `java.time`. Consulte a documentação e veja quais classes são mapeadas para quais tipos no banco de dados.

Comment: Certo hkotsubo, agradeço pela ótima explicação, consegui entender melhor o funcionamento. Vou realizar as alterações aqui no código. Acredito que vai funcionar.  Abraços.

Answer (score 0):

```java
// data: Data e hora original
// horas: Horas que se deseja asicionar
public Date adicionaHoras(Date data, int horas) {
   Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance(); // Cria um objeto de data
   calendario.setTime(data); // Inicia o objeto com a data original
   calendario.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, horas); // Adiciona as horas necessárias

   return calendario.getTime(); // Retorna a hora formatada
}
```

Comment: Olá Elihofni, tudo bem?

Não consegui atribuir '23:59:59.999' ao meu date.

A função altera a data que recebe e incrementa as horas que passa no 'int horas'.

Obrigado.

Comment: Somar uma certa quantidade de horas não garante o horário final será 23:59:59.999, o certo é setar as horas, minutos, segundos e milissegundos com esses valores