# Quando usar a classe Date ou a classe Calendar?

Tags: java, datetime

Preciso descobrir a média de tempo para um programa de estacionamento qual melhor solução e qual o mercado profissional usa?

Comment: Se for média de tempo, então vc precisa trabalhar com durações (que [**não** é o mesmo que data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/374349/112052)), então nem `Date` nem `Calendar` servem. Se estiver usando Java >= 8 pode usar `java.time.Duration` (ou ainda, um `int` ou `long' mesmo, contendo a duração total em segundos, milissegundos ou qualquer outra unidade que vc precisar)

Comment: Complementando, se estiver usando Java >= 8, não use nenhuma delas, prefira usar as classes do [pacote `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classe [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) é suficiente para grande maioria dos casos. Ela existe para representar um ponto na linha do tempo, ou seja, você tem um número que representa o ano, mês, dia, hora, segundo, e algumas casas de fração de segundo. Isso é mais do que suficiente para quase todos os casos na maioria das aplicações.

Mas em alguns raros casos pode precisar de mais que isto, e é aí que entra a classe [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html). Ela tem informações extras como fuso horário e informações para localização internacional e melhores ferramentas de formatação. Não é algo que um estacionamento precise, então parece que não precisa pensar muito nela, o mercado usa pouco.

Note que estas classes não servem para marcar uma quantidade de tempo como muitos fazem. Você não pode usar esta classe para dizer que algo leva 5 horas por exemplo, este é um caso para usar a classe [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html). Então para marcar a hora de entrada ou de saída a `Date` está de boa, mas para marcara quanto tempo o veículo ficou estacionado seria a `Duration`.

E concordo com o [comentário do hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/565754/quando-usar-a-classe-date-ou-a-classe-calendar/565756#comment999439_565754). Desde Java 8 existem novas classes de tempo já que as primeiras continham falhas, ainda que não seja tão comum as pessoas usarem, seria o ideal. As novas classes foram baseadas em uma biblioteca chamada [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) que resolvia problemas da biblioteca padrão do Java e agora podemos dizer que o padrão seria tudo o que está em `java.time`. Provavelmente o ideal seria usar [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). Se for garantido que o estacionamento não trabalha com pernoite então apenas a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) pode ser suficiente. Para quantidade de tempo a `Duration` já é essa nova API e está ok.